# Can I use make Async calls through AdoTemplate?

Tags: c#, ado.net, spring.net

I'm writing a small Spring.NET application that would really benefit from concurrent DB calls, but I don't see any obvious way to perform an async operation on the [AdoTemplate](http://www.springframework.net/doc-1.1-M1/sdk/2.0/html/Spring.Data~Spring.Data.AdoTemplate.html) class that Spring.NET uses to wrap data access?  Am I limited to manually pooling and threading against the AdoTemplate class?

Comment: AFAIK, you'll have to do threading your self. What kind of pooling would you like to do?

Comment: @Marijn If possible I'd prefer to let the connection pooling handle that, and only keep one of the `AdoTemplate` if that wouldn't bottleneck.  I was working on it last night and there's nothing stateful about my business class so I could use it un-pooled.  I guess I just need to write the logic to split the requests to multiple queues/thread (or each to the threadpool) and put them back together ...